# Java Bean: how <jsp:setProperty> in <jsp:useBean> is generated into Java Code

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

For example, I have this code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="dog" class="Dog" scope="application">
     <jsp:setProperty name="dog" property="breed" value="House Dog !!!"/>
</jsp:useBean>
```

I know how it works. But, sometimes, I change some some code in this, for example: "dog" to "newDog", I will meet error or unguested-result (with me).

Please give me how above code is generated into Java. (maybe just a main idea)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSPs ultimately get generated to `.java` classes which get compiled as servlets. Check the server's work folder. In case of Tomcat, a `/test.jsp` gets generated as `/org/apache/jsp/test_jsp.java` file in Tomcat's `/work` folder.

The following lines

```html
<jsp:useBean id="dog" class="com.example.Dog" scope="application">
     <jsp:setProperty name="dog" property="breed" value="House Dog !!!"/>
</jsp:useBean>
```

*(the only change I made is adding a package; packageless classes are Bad™)*

are generated as

```java
  com.example.Dog dog = null;
  synchronized (application) {
    dog = (com.example.Dog) _jspx_page_context.getAttribute("dog", javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
    if (dog == null){
      dog = new com.example.Dog();
      _jspx_page_context.setAttribute("dog", dog, javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
      out.write("\n");
      out.write("     ");
      org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.introspecthelper(_jspx_page_context.findAttribute("dog"), "breed", "House Dog !!!", null, null, false);
      out.write('\n');
    }
  }
```

Tomcat is open source, according to its source code, the `JspRuntimeLibrary#introspecthelper()` method delegates to `internalIntrospecthelper()` which ultimately does this:

```
Method method = null;
Class<?> type = null;
Class<?> propertyEditorClass = null;
try {
    java.beans.BeanInfo info
        = java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(bean.getClass());
    if ( info != null ) {
        java.beans.PropertyDescriptor pd[]
            = info.getPropertyDescriptors();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < pd.length ; i++) {
            if ( pd[i].getName().equals(prop) ) {
                method = pd[i].getWriteMethod();
                type   = pd[i].getPropertyType();
                propertyEditorClass = pd[i].getPropertyEditorClass();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( method != null ) {
        if (type.isArray()) {
            if (request == null) {
                throw new JasperException(
                    Localizer.getMessage("jsp.error.beans.setproperty.noindexset"));
            }
            Class<?> t = type.getComponentType();
            String[] values = request.getParameterValues(param);
            //XXX Please check.
            if(values == null) return;
            if(t.equals(String.class)) {
                method.invoke(bean, new Object[] { values });
            } else {
                createTypedArray (prop, bean, method, values, t,
                                  propertyEditorClass); 
            }
        } else {
            if(value == null || (param != null && value.equals(""))) return;
            Object oval = convert(prop, value, type, propertyEditorClass);
            if ( oval != null )
                method.invoke(bean, new Object[] { oval });
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Throwable thr = ExceptionUtils.unwrapInvocationTargetException(ex);
    ExceptionUtils.handleThrowable(thr);
    throw new JasperException(ex);
}
```

You see, it's using [`java.beans.Introspector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) to get bean information and properties by [`BeanInfo#getPropertyDescriptors()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html#getPropertyDescriptors%28%29). The desired `<jsp:setProperty>` method is obtained as [`java.lang.reflect.Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) by [`PropertyDescriptor#getWriteMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html#getWriteMethod%28%29). Finally it uses the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to invoke the method.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is generated:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.setBreed("House Dog !!!");
```

The dog in setProperty is a reference to the Class Dog of useBean.
Hope you understand this

Comment: No. I know you are missing many lines of code :) I know because I just don't understand how <jsp:setProperty> is really generated.

Comment: You see how this works: 1. The use bean has an id, class and scope attribute. The id is the name or variable that will be used to instantiate the class(FQCN) that you pass to the class attribute. 2. So the setProperty method uses the value of the name attribute to locate the instance of the Dog Class, once it locates this class, it will use reflection to set the breed property of the Dog class located with the value provided in the value attribute of the setProperty. This is why the value of id attribute of usebean and name attribute of setProperty must match.