# How to use JSP EL insinde tag attribute

Tags: java, jsp, el

Is it possible to use EL expression inside tag attribute?

I wrote following code

```
<jsp:useBean id="beans" class="pl.adamski.heroku.Beans"/>
<jsp:useBean id="questions" class="${beans.questionManager}"/>
```

but it doesn't compile, I get following error:

```
The value for the useBean class attribute ${beans.questionManager} is invalid
```

Comment: Not like that, no. If you want to use it in an html tag's attribute, that would be fine, but you're putting it in a jsp:useBean tag, which is processed before the EL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation the class attribute does not allow the EL

"class="package.class"
Instantiates a bean from a class, using the new keyword and the class constructor. The class must not be
abstract and must have a public, no−argument constructor. The package and class name are case sensitive." see [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs81/pdf/files/workshop/JSPTagsReference.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

No, what you are attempting is not allowed. Try looking at the code generated from the tag lib and it will explain why this is not allowed. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285209/java-bean-how-jspsetproperty-in-jspusebean-is-generated-into-java-code)